# How to do an if not conditional test with jquery?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a  tag that appears on an image when the mouse enters the image. When I want to go on the link with the mouse the link logically  disappears because i used `.mouseleave()` function to hide the link when the mouse leaves the image.

I thought to do a conditional test for the `.mouseleave()` as follow:

```
if(!$("#linkId").mouseenter()){
//...
}
```

I tried with `.`not().mousenter() instead of `!` not

But it does not work.. When I enter on the link, it stays and it it never leaves...

Thank you

Sam

Comment: What do you want to test for? What do you expect `.mouseenter()` to return?

Comment: I think you want to do mouseover instead. Then you wont lose focus

Comment: Also, remember, those are events. They dont return true/false when they happen, they just DO something not return something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put both, the link and the image in a container and assign the event handler to the container instead. You can position the link with CSS.

As the link and the image are children of the parent, the `mouseleave` event is not triggered when you hover over the link.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="image"></div> <!-- the div is just an example -->
    <a id="link" href="#">Some link</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#parent {
    position: relative;
}

/* used div for demo only */
#image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#parent').hover(function() {
    $('#link').toggle();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kuRHx/)

---

`$("#linkId").mouseenter()` is not doing what you think it does. It does not test whether the mouse is over the link or not, it generates a `mouseenter` event on the link.

Comment: Thank you but I cannot do that because the <img> needs to be independent as it is recuperated by a plugin in order to create a slide show (plg spacegallery). If I do that the plg does not work correctly. This plugin does not let me add a link on the images this is what I am trying to do. I need this plugin because my boss loves this effect... and I did not find another plugin that does the same effect with a link....

Answer (score 0):

Use `hover()`, and either bind it to both the link and the image, or have the image within the link element.

i.e.

```
<img src="example.gif" alt="" id="showme" style="display:none" />
<a href="#" id="hoverme">Hover me</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#hoverme,#showme').hover(function(){
        $('#showme').toggle();
    });
</script>
```